# select option white-space CSS not being applied in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-select

I have a simple demo at [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sun21170/hw1zrbzm/3/) with a select element and I would like to set the white-space attribute for each `select option`.

My CSS is correct, yet the same attribute value that is for `select` gets applied. This is shown in screen shot below taken from FireFox developer tool. The stylsheet `forms.css` appears to be coming from Firefox browser. *I am using version 57.0 (64-bit) of FireFox.*

**Question**: Is there any way I can apply the below CSS in FireFox? Or maybe it's not possible since the CSS is injected by FireFox?

**CSS**

```
select option {
   white-space: normal !important;
 }
```

**Select element html**

```
<select size="6" name="ListBox1" id="ListBox1" style="width:100px;">
  <option value="Item 1 dsdds  sdsdsdsd sdsd sdsd sds xyz" title="Item 1 dsdds  sdsdsdsd sdsd sdsd sds xyz">Item 1 dsdds sdsdsdsd sdsd sdsd sds xyz</option>
  <option value="Item 2" title="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="Item 3 gfgf kgkgkg kgkkg abc" title="Item 3 gfgf kgkgkg kgkkg abc">Item 3 gfgf kgkgkg kgkkg abc</option>
  <option value="Item 4" title="Item 4">Item 4</option>
  <option value="Item 5" title="Item 5">Item 5</option>
  <option value="Item 6" title="Item 6">Item 6</option>
</select>
```

**Screenshot of Computed CSS being applied to select option element**

[image: FireFox Dev Tool Screenshot for computed style]

Answer (score 0):

According to [research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), normal should be supported by Firefox. The only modifier I see is the -moz addition, but this doesn't let you change it directly and just wraps the text like it should do by default.

```
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
```

You could try that since I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish with it. It might work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem, since an important CSS rule should apply like its doing in Chrome or Opera or Edge. If Firfox supports `white-space:normal`, then it should apply the important rule in my case, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the CSS after + content option.
Firefox 105.0.2

```
<select>
<option data-text="long text long text"></option>
<option data-text="long text long text"></option>
<option data-text="long text long text"></option>
</select>

select option::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: anywhere;
  white-space: initial;
}
```